# double from fraction string iPhone

Tags: iphone, arrays, numbers

I have an array of strings that are fractions (1/3, 2/5) etc. I need to take these strings and use them as doubles for calculations. The fractions go into the arrays as strings. Why isn't the below code working?

```
NSString *localString = [array objectAtIndex:1];
double NewDouble = [localString doubleValue];
```

I get the first int in each string (1 instead of .333 & 2 instead of .4 from above).

I'm missing something easy and it's driving me crazy.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot take a `NSString`representing a fraction and demand its doubleValue. You have to split the string and calculate the fraction manually.

Comment: NSString *newString = [array objectAtIndex:row];
        NSArray *listItems = [newString componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
        double NewDouble = [[listItems objectAtIndex:0]doubleValue] / [[listItems objectAtIndex:1]doubleValue];